# Using FuncUnit .click() within frame

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, frame, qunit, funcunit

I'm trying to simulate a user click on an element within a frame tag using FuncUnit.prototype.click() and am having no success.

I've tried chaining the click() call like so,

```
S('#main').contents().find('#Planning').visible('Planning tab visible').click();
```

as well as attepting to click via callback,

```
        S('#main').contents().find('#Planning').visible('Planning tab visible', function() {
        S('#main').contents().find('#Planning').click();
    });
```

and neither have worked, in both cases the desired element, #Planning, is visible but neither actually preform the click. The first method, being chaining the call to click(), shows in console that FuncUnit is at least attempting to click

```
steal.js INFO: Clicking #Planning
```

where as attempting to click via callback does not seem to even attempt to click. Considering the element is visible I don't think the issue is that the frame is not yet loaded by the time the click is attempted.

Can anyone identify the issue and/or suggest a work around?